# How do I create a method which function is to show the content of an ArrayList's objects?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I have a problem regarding creating a method which function is to show the content of an ArrayList's object.

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to explain it further in short, it would take several pages of code (different classes) to show you exactly.

Comment: If you mean you want to show meaningful representation of your objects inside your arraylist, override toString() for your Object

Comment: create a method that takes an `ArrayList` as parameter, and iterates through this list and displays the elements.

Comment: It'll be really easier to give help if you showed what you have tried so far.

Comment: for example 

public Article getAll(orderLineArrayList>)(){

Comment: "I have a problem but I can't explain what it is, can anyone help?" This doesn't give us a lot to go on! Help us help you. Whittle the problem down to something specific (chances are you can show it in just a few lines).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for this:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("elmement0");
    list.add("elmement1");
    list.add("elmement2");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.toArray()));
```

`deepToString()` is recursive. For example Eclipse uses this method when you are debugging your code.

This will print out:

> [elmement0, elmement1, elmement2]

You also have to override the `toString()` method in the class you are storing in your `List`.